# How do I specify team permissions on github3py

Tags: python, git, github, github3.py

I'm trying to do a simple script of adding repositories to a team with github3py.

The `add_repo(repo, team)` method doesn't have anyway to specify what kind of permission I want my team to have, according to : http://github3.readthedocs.io/en/develop/orgs.html

vs in github docs, it says you can pass the permission as parameter: 
https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/teams/#add-or-update-team-repository

so is this just not implemented in github3.py or am I confused?

I want to be able to add a team with read and write permissions. This defaults to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like there's another method with the same name but for object `Team`

```
add_repository(repository, permission=u'')
Add repository to this team.

Parameters: 
repository (str) – (required), form: ‘user/repo’
permission (str) – (optional), (‘pull’, ‘push’, ‘admin’)
```

This way you can specify permissions.